# Error while compiling U-boot-1.1.6 on fedora 8 with ELDK cross compiler

Tags: u-boot

I am compiling U-boot, for yosemite board. when i hit make all, fallowing errors will occurred.
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '.depend' needed by 'libcommon.a'. Stop

Comment: PATH added correctly.

Comment: How did you configure U-Boot for your board?